# Confused trying to prove $\lim_\limits{x \to 5} \sqrt{x+4} = 3$

Tags: calculus

I was watching a youtube video on epsilon-delta proofs when I came across this argument.  We wanted to show $\lim_\limits{x \to 5} \sqrt{x+4} = 3$.  He started the proof of by :
$|\sqrt{x+4}-3|<\epsilon \implies -\epsilon <\sqrt{x+4}-3<\epsilon \implies 3 - \epsilon < \sqrt{x+4} < 3 + \epsilon$
The next step was what confused me - he then stated that :
$(3-\epsilon)^2<x+4<(3+\epsilon)^2$.  I was wondering if this was correct since we do not know if $3-\epsilon \geq 0 $.  Am I correct or did I miss something?

If that squaring step was indeed incorrect, I was also wondering how to find $\delta$.

Thanks

Comment: Not correct without an explanation, but that explanation exists. In the definition of limit you need to get $|\sqrt{x+4}-3|<\epsilon$ for certain collection of values of $x$ that you will construct. Namely, the $x$s with $0<|x-5|<\delta$ for a delta that you will choose. If you manage to get them to satisfy the inequality when $\epsilon<3$, then the same collection satisfies the inequality with any other larger $\epsilon$. Therefore, you can assume that $\epsilon<3$.

Comment: Ok I see, I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can let

$\epsilon_2 = min\{3,\epsilon\}$

Then if we complete our proof using $\epsilon_2$, we know it works for $\epsilon$ since $\epsilon_2 \le \epsilon$

$(3-\epsilon_2)^2<x+4<(3+\epsilon_2)^2$

$9 - 6\epsilon_2 + \epsilon_2^2 < x+4<9+6\epsilon_2+\epsilon_2^2$

$ - 6\epsilon_2 + \epsilon_2^2 < x-5<6\epsilon_2+\epsilon_2^2$

$ - (6\epsilon_2 - \epsilon_2^2) < x-5<6\epsilon_2+\epsilon_2^2$

Note we know that $6\epsilon_2-\epsilon_2^2 > 0$ since $\epsilon_2 \le 3$

Now we can let $\delta = min\{6\epsilon_2-\epsilon_2^2, 6\epsilon_2+\epsilon_2^2\} = 6\epsilon_2-\epsilon_2^2$, since $\epsilon_2 \gt 0$

Now you need to show using this $\delta$ that $|x-5| \lt \delta \implies |\sqrt{x+4}-3| \lt \epsilon_2 \le \epsilon$

Answer (score 3):

You know that $\sqrt{x+4} \ge 0$. So, you may assume the left-hand side of your inequality is

$$\max\{0, 3-\epsilon\}$$